# How did Ramanujan calculate these interesting values for $e$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, euler-mascheroni-constant

While reading a mini-bio about Ramanujan, there was an equation that I found somewhat intriguing:$$e^{\pi\sqrt{58}}=24591257751.99999982\ldots\tag1$$
This is interesting in the way that $e^{\pi\sqrt{58}}$ is very close to $24591257752$, and how Ramanujan managed to calculate such a large number back when computers didn't exist!
Others include
\begin{equation}35\sqrt{\pi}\ln 2=42.9999986\ldots\tag2\\ 51\ln(36\pi)-2e^\pi+\sqrt[4]{21}=196.99999991695\ldots\\ e^{{\frac \pi 4\sqrt{102}}}=800\sqrt3+196\sqrt{51}\\\vdots\end{equation}

And there are much more. So, I'm wondering:

> **Main Question:** Is there some sort of formula, trick or follow-through that you can use that enables you to calculate other fascinating $e$ equations that are very close to an integer?
>
> *Note:* I'm not the best at mathematics. In fact, I haven't even started Calculus yet. I would *love* it if the answer also had a detailed description of how you solved this.

Comment: $e^{\pi \sqrt{163}}$ is even more impressive. See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4544/why-is-e-pi-sqrt163-almost-an-integer and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_integer.

Comment: It's only 19 significant digits. If you have $\pi$ and $\sqrt{58}$ available to that precision, computing the exponential takes only about 20 terms of the power series -- not something you jot down in a minute, but not something you need to spend years on either.

Comment: I have edited the question... Is it okay to reopen it now?

Comment: It is still a duplicate, since the theory behind those formulas is very complicated, and the [answers given](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/101868/276986) are enough. See how it mentions [Heegner numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heegner_number#Detail) i.e. (complicated) properties of number fields and [modular forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_form), related to the [Ramanujan-Sato series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan%E2%80%93Sato_series)

Comment: @user1952009 Okay then. I give up. *But*, is there a pdf of 'Sur la théorie des equations modulaires' in english?

Comment: @Frank The modular forms are not of your level. And before computers were invented, it was common to run such hard computation up to $20$ digits

Comment: The calculation of $e^{\pi\sqrt{58}}$ is much simpler as Ramanujan did it. The calculation depends on the value of class invariant $$g_{58}=\sqrt{\frac{5+\sqrt{29}}{2}}$$ and the equation $$64(g_{58}^{24}+g_{58}^{-24}) =e^{\pi\sqrt{58}}-24+4372e^{-\pi\sqrt{58}}+\dots$$ All of this is based on the theory of modular equations and presented by Ramanujan in his classic paper *Modular Equations and Approximations to $\pi$*. The value in your equation $(1)$ appears to be directly taken from the same paper. He gave more examples of such calculations in that paper.