# What is the history behind the discovery of the almost-integer values of $ e^{\pi \sqrt{d}} $?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, math-history, modular-forms

It's well-known that $ e^{\pi \sqrt{d}} $ is almost an integer when $ d $ is taken to be one of the large Heegner numbers $ d = 43, 67, 163 $.

I'm interested to know what the history of this discovery was like. Specifically, did the "empirical discovery" of the almost-integer values of $ e^{\pi \sqrt d} $ come before or after the theory of complex multiplication was already well understood? In other words, was the discovery that $ e^{\pi \sqrt d} $ was almost an integer for some small values of $ d $ accidental or was it motivated by known properties of the $ j $-invariant?

Comment: Related: [How did Hermite calculate $e^{\pi\sqrt{163}}$ in 1859?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/101376/how-did-hermite-calculate-e-pi-sqrt163-in-1859)

Comment: $e^{\pi\sqrt{d}} $ is almost an integer even when $d$ is not Heegner number like for $d=58$ ($\mathbb{Q} (\sqrt{-58})$ has class number 2).

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Yeah, that's why I stated the implication only in one direction :)

Answer (score 3):

On p. 138 of Ranjan Roy's *Elliptic and Modular Functions from Gauss to Dedekind to Hecke*, he writes that Hermite gave the $q$-expansion of the $j$-function (not using modern notation) and from this estimated $e^{\pi\sqrt{43}}$ and $e^{\pi\sqrt{163}}$ as being very close to integers.

Comment: I think there was some discussion of this in the linked question as well, but are we confident that Hermite knew $ j((1 + \sqrt{-163})/2) $ should be an integer because $ 163 $ is a Heegner number? If so, I think the important question is whether Hermite was the first person to notice almost-integers of the form $ e^{\pi \sqrt d} $.

Comment: See the bottom of p. 48 of Hermite's book : https://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/id/PPN598770909?tify=%7B%22pages%22%3A%5B56%5D%2C%22pan%22%3A%7B%22x%22%3A0.476%2C%22y%22%3A0.608%7D%2C%22view%22%3A%22info%22%2C%22zoom%22%3A0.798%7D.  He refers there to $e^{\pi\sqrt{\Delta}}$ for suitable integers $\Delta$ as "transcendental", but its transcendence was not proved until the Gelfond-Schneider theorem in 1934 (view $e^{\pi\sqrt{\Delta}}$ as a value of $i^{i\sqrt{\Delta}} = a^b$ for algebraic $a = i$ and $b = i\sqrt{\Delta}$).