# $exp(x)-\frac{x^{2}}{a}+\frac{x}{b}-1=0$

Tags: polynomials, lambert-w

I have an equation that can be very likely solved with the Lambert function but looks a bit messy:

$exp(x)-\frac{x^2}{a}+\frac{x}{b}-1=0$, and $a>0$, $b\geq1$ (if constraints help).

Any idea how to get x out of this in the closed form?

Cheers,
p

Comment: Consider Taylor series expansion of $e^x$ say to 3 terms around zero, you could get a quadratic equation that may be useful as an approximate root.

Comment: Approximation is easy, though, I need the exact analytical solution :)

Comment: It helps to specify the domain of $x$, you could replace $e^x$ by a single fraction as in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/71357/approximation-of-e-x but an closed form is probably not possible.

Comment: $$x\in [0;1] $$

Comment: I assume that the approximation in the provided like is excellent. Plot it against the $e^x$ and see how good it is.

Comment: Yes, unless we can find an analytical solution, 3d order polynomial of Taylor around 0 is more than enough for an approximation.

Answer (score 0):

Unless factorization can be done, this requires a [generalization of the Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function#Generalizations). See [Taylor series for generalized Lambert W function](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1801.09904.pdf). In essence you can get a series expansion for $x$ in terms of the other variables using [Lagrange inversion theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem#Lambert_W_function), but it is likely messy.

Aside from that, not much more can be done to the problem other than numerical computation.